# How to capture text between two markers? regex php

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture text between `<a href="tag/hourse">hourse</a>`

HTML

```
<div class="tags">
  <a href="tag/hourse">hourse</a>
  <a href="tag/pik">pik</a>
  <a href="tag/turtle">turtle</a>
  <a href="tag/pillot">pillot</a>
  <a href="tag/glass">glass</a>
  <a href="tag/dog">dog</a>
  <a href="tag/cat">cat</a>
  <a href="tag/fish">fish</a>
</div>
```

My regular expression

```
preg_match_all("/<div\s*class="tags">\s*<a\shref=".*"\s*>(.*)</a>/i", $html, $arr);
```

It doesn't work correctly because it just capture the first data "hourse" and not the following "pik, turtle, etc". Is there another way?

p.d: I know that is not a good idea use regular expression to capture html tags, but I wonder if this example has a solution.

Comment: @JohnConde I know using the DOM it's more easy, but I'd like to know if it has a solution using regular expression.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't contain the string you're looking for. There is no `class="exa-1"` anywhere in there. Also, HTML-parsing is not a job for regular expressions. Use a [real parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Do you use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` ? do you have `m` multiline flat in you regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = '<div class="tags">
  <a href="tag/hourse" class="cloud-2">hourse</a>
  <a href="tag/pik" class="cloud-4">pik</a>
  <a href="tag/turtle" class="cloud-2">turtle</a>
  <a href="tag/pillot" class="cloud-2">pillot</a>
  <a href="tag/glass" class="cloud-1">glass</a>
  <a href="tag/dog" class="cloud-2">dog</a>
  <a href="tag/cat" class="cloud-2">cat</a>
  <a href="tag/fish" class="cloud-1">fish</a></div>';


preg_match_all('/\<a href=".*"\>(.*)\<\/a\>/', $str, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the strings you seek

Comment: this works, but is not the complete code, inside this html file there are other urls, that's why I inlcude <div class="tags">

Comment: What is it you're trying to capture then?

Comment: I just want to capture text between <a></a> that are within <div class="tags"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Regex should not be used for this kind of task, but in simple code you will be good with regex pattern

```
(?<=>)[^<>]*?[^\s<>][^<>]*?(?=<)
```

PHP code will be then

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=>)[^<>]*?[^\s<>][^<>]*?(?=<)/', $str, $matches);
```

See demo [**here**](http://ideone.com/DHEmYY).

Answer (score 0):

The default of regex check per line and not all content then you can use this regex to capture  hourse, pik, turtle or other:

```
preg_match_all("/tag\/([\w_]+)/", "content of inputs", $matches);

return

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => tag/hourse
            [1] => tag/pik
            [2] => tag/turtle
            [3] => tag/pillot
            [4] => tag/glass
            [5] => tag/dog
            [6] => tag/cat
            [7] => tag/fish
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => hourse
            [1] => pik
            [2] => turtle
            [3] => pillot
            [4] => glass
            [5] => dog
            [6] => cat
            [7] => fish
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMDocument, like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument; @$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourFile.php');
// for XML use @$dom->load('yourfile.rss') file extension may differ
function getElementsByClassName($domDoc, $className){
  $all = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('*');
  foreach($all as $e) {
    if(!$e->hasAttribute('class')){
      continue;
    }
    if(!in_array($className, preg_split('/\s+/', $all->getAttribute('class')))){
       continue;
    }
    $r[] = $e;
  }
  return $r;
}
$tags = getElementsByClassName($dom, 'tags'); $result = '<dl>';
foreach($tags[0]->childNodes as $c){
  if($c->nodeType === 1){
    $result .= "<dt>{$c->textContent}</dt><dd>{$c->getAttribute('href')}</dd>";
  }
}
$result .= '</dl>';
echo $result;
```